# кнопки пагинации не реагируют на нажатия

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Доброго времени суток! Кнопки пагинации, описанные как 
paginationBtns не реагируют. Однако, объекты "кнопок" для пагинации выводятся в консоль, также все нужное рендерится в шаблон. Вот код:

модель

```
let model = {
   users: [],
   filterString: "",

   get filteredUsers() {
       let _filter = model.filterString.toLowerCase().trim();

         return !_filter ? this.users : this.users.filter(x => {
               return x.username.toLowerCase().includes(_filter);
           });
   }
};
```

вот основная часть - здесь в цикле предписываю реакцию на Click для каждой кнопки - после рендеринга кнопок на страницу ( рендеринг внутри ф-и requestUsers).

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

   let inputEl = document.getElementById('name_input');

   inputEl.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      model.filterString = event.target.value;
      requestUsers(3, 1, model.filterString);
    });

   let paginationBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('paginationButton'); //NodeList of buttons")

        console.log(paginationBtns, paginationBtns.length); //длина коллекции кнопок почему-то(?) нулевая, поэтому в цикл не заходит вообще

        for (let i = 0; i < paginationBtns.length;i++){

            //console.log(i,paginationBtns[i]);

            console.log("ITERATION"); 

            paginationBtns[i].addEventListener('click', 
            function(event) {
                console.log("СLICK!"); //не выводится при нажатии на 
             кнопку
                console.log(event.target.innerText);
                requestUsers(3, parseInt(event.target.innerText), 
              inputEl.innerText);
             }); 
          }


  requestUsers(3, 1);
 });
```

вот ф-я requestUsers, которая рендерит список пользователей и пагинацию и вспомогательные для нее ф-и.

```
// getting users via AJAX from API
 function requestUsers(perPage, pageIndex, search_string) {
   let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

     ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
       console.log(ajax.readyState, ajax.response, ajax.status);
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       let result = JSON.parse(ajax.response);

       model.users = result.users;

       let pagesCount = result.pagesCount;
       console.log("COUNT" + pagesCount);

       renderUsers(pageIndex);
       console.log('users rendered!');
       renderPagination(perPage, pagesCount, pageIndex);
     }
   };
   if (!search_string){
       ajax.open("GET", "/api/v1/users/" + perPage + "/" + pageIndex, 
       true);
   }
    else{
       ajax.open("GET", "/api/v1/users/search/" + search_string + "/" 
       + perPage + "/" + pageIndex, true);
   }
   ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   ajax.send();
 }

  //rendering users inside special area
  function renderUsers(pageIndex) {

   let usersEl = document.getElementById('users');
   filteredUsers = model.filteredUsers;
   console.log(filteredUsers);

   let template = document.getElementById("user-list-
    template").innerHTML;
    let renderedHTML = Mustache.render(template, {users: 
    filteredUsers});
    usersEl.innerHTML = renderedHTML;
  }

 //rendering pagination buttons
  function renderPagination(perPage, pagesCount, pageIndex) {

   let paginationEl = document.getElementById('pagination');

    let paginationBtns = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++){
        paginationBtns.push({"index": i });
    }   

   let template = document.getElementById("paginate-
   template").innerHTML;
   let renderedHTML = Mustache.render(template, {paginationBtns: 
    paginationBtns});
    paginationEl.innerHTML = renderedHTML;

 }
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Функция getElementsById не существует, так как подразумевается, что id элементов уникален.

> document.getElementById() Returns the element that has the ID
> attribute with the specified value
>
> document.getElementsByClassName() Returns a NodeList containing all
> elements with the specified class name
>
> document.getElementsByName()  Returns a NodeList containing all
> elements with a specified name
>
> document.getElementsByTagName()   Returns
> a NodeList containing all elements with the specified tag name

Однако, в 2017-м году самый модный вариант:

> document.querySelector()  Returns the first element that matches a
> specified CSS selector(s) in the document
>
> document.querySelectorAll() Returns a static NodeList containing all
> elements that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document

В дальнейшем рекомендую использовать встроенный в бразуер дебаггер, чтобы точно понимать какие значения получают переменные в процессе

Comment: Пробовал через getElementsByClassName -   возвращает HTML-коллекцию, где каждому элементу приписываю событие click - но все равно ничего не происходит.